# Animated Gif not playing in Backround worker in wp7. It was look like normal Image

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I am doing time-consuming operations are executed on the Main Thread on WP7. Normally this case the user interface can stop responding to user input  & it won’t update bindings.
So that I have used backgroundWorker for Update UI. Its update UI. In my project, user control have gif animated image for loading condition. In this case the animated image not playing. It look like normal .jpg or png Image. But it have animation. Normaly playing in my project with different condition.

```
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
         bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
         bw.DoWork += (s, a) =>
         {                
             Dispatch(ImageFill);                
         };

         bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
         {
            PopOpen = false;
         };
         PopOpen = true;
         bw.RunWorkerAsync();     

   //dispatch function
    private void Dispatch(object ImageFill)
    {
        PersistentData.AppDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {                   
            Point p1 = new Point();
            Image imgDraw = new Image();
            ............ //functionality 
        } 
    }

I don't know how to handle that. Pls anyone known help me.
```

Comment: sorry, It not app loading, some functionality taken time for that used. I am using ImageTools Dll, I have playing gif image. Its normally working.

Comment: pls any one known help me. this problem is frustrating me. I could not find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Wp7 doesn't support the GIF format image.

[**For Animation in Wp7 you can refer this link(spl for splash screen).**](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-Splash-Screens-in-WP7-ndash-Creating-animated-Splash-Screen)

Answer (score -1):

Pls refer this Article for Playing Gif image, this would help

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/show-gif-images-in-windows-phone-7-1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.

Comment: i just given link for playing Gif image in windows phone 7, that is it.